# Bloodborne Old Hunter Edition

Tags: bloodborne

I just recently got the Old Hunter Edition and everyone said that you'll be able to use the old save file from the regular base game. So I popped in the Old Hunter disc, hoping that my save file is still intact but I didn't see anything at all. So I tried out a tons of method from google but it still doesn't work! None of it. I didn't have the usual error that most people get, the error that says "Game incomplete".

I tried downloading my old save files to the Old Hunter Edition but it didn't worked either. I followed every single possible steps but none of it helped. I would greatly appreciated any help to solve this. I spent all my blood, sweat and tears to reach lvl100 with my trusty 10+ Tonitrus!!! Please help!!

I heard that you'll need to wait for about an hour or 2 to let it completely installed. I'm trying this right now and in the meantime, I'm redownloading my regular base game back since I thought the Old Hunter will work so I deleted it.

Comment: Might help adding some links to things you tried rather than allude to them. Also, are you saying you only have the DLC installed and not the base game?

Comment: From the "Old Hunters" version I found on amazon, I would say that you need the base-game installed too. A little text on the disc says "Full version required". This points to the fact that you have ti install base-game plus DLCs

Answer (score 1):

Everyone was wrong. The games are considered different thus saves are incompatible.

Note that the same thing happen if you have the same game but in different regions.

Comment: Any supporting evidence on this? The dupe link in comments seem to indicate they are compatible.

Comment: They are different games.